Android Studio: How do I take a value provided by a user and use it to fill out a sentence madlib style?
So i want the user to provide me with word. Below that, I have a couple of sentences. I want to take the word provided by them and put it in the sentence below. For example.
Your Name: [user provided word]
Hello [user provided word], thanks for stopping by!
If this question has been answered, please post the link. Nothing i googled turned up what i wanted. It possible i didn't have the right search terms.
Thanks!
